# Strange syntax in JavaScript article

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking at this article here:

http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/no-promises.html#comment-3064041816

The author Dr. Axel, references his example library which looks as follows (verbatim):

```
  /**
     * Run the generator object `genObj`,
     * report results via the callbacks in `callbacks`.
     */
    function runGenObj(genObj, callbacks = undefined) {
        handleOneNext();

        /**
         * Handle one invocation of `next()`:
         * If there was a `prevResult`, it becomes the parameter.
         * What `next()` returns is what we have to run next.
         * The `success` callback triggers another round,
         * with the result assigned to `prevResult`.
         */
        function handleOneNext(prevResult = null) {
            try {
                let yielded = genObj.next(prevResult); // may throw
                if (yielded.done) {
                    if (yielded.value !== undefined) {
                        // Something was explicitly returned:
                        // Report the value as a result to the caller
                        callbacks.success(yielded.value);
                    }
                } else {
                    setTimeout(runYieldedValue, 0, yielded.value);
                }
            }
            // Catch unforeseen errors in genObj
            catch (error) {
                if (callbacks) {
                    callbacks.failure(error);
                } else {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        }
        function runYieldedValue(yieldedValue) {
            if (yieldedValue === undefined) {
                // If code yields `undefined`, it wants callbacks
                handleOneNext(callbacks);
            } else if (Array.isArray(yieldedValue)) {
                runInParallel(yieldedValue);
            } else {
                // Yielded value is a generator object
                runGenObj(yieldedValue, {
                    success(result) {
                        handleOneNext(result);
                    },
                    failure(err) {
                        genObj.throw(err);
                    },
                });
            }
        }

        function runInParallel(genObjs) {
            let resultArray = new Array(genObjs.length);
            let resultCountdown = genObjs.length;
            for (let [i,genObj] of genObjs.entries()) {
                runGenObj(genObj, {
                    success(result) {
                        resultArray[i] = result;
                        resultCountdown--;
                        if (resultCountdown <= 0) {
                            handleOneNext(resultArray);
                        }
                    },
                    failure(err) {
                        genObj.throw(err);
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function run(genFunc) {
        runGenObj(genFunc());
    }
```

this syntax checks out on my machine and runs just fine, but I cannot figure out how these two pieces of code from above 'run':

exhibit A:

```
               //
               runGenObj(yieldedValue, { // this is not a function, is it an object?
                success(result) {
                    handleOneNext(result);
                },
                failure(err) {
                    genObj.throw(err);
                },
            });
              //
```

exhibit b:

```
          //
    runGenObj(genObj, {    // same thing here (?)
        success(result) {
            resultArray[i] = result;
            resultCountdown--;
            if (resultCountdown <= 0) {
                handleOneNext(resultArray);
            }
        },
        failure(err) {
            genObj.throw(err);
        },
    });
      //
```

it must be some ES6 thing, can anybody tell me what that's about?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a shorthand for declaring things in an object literal.

Example where the object gets a key `site` with the value of the variable `site`

```
let site = "SC"
console.log({
  site
})
```

Example where goodbye is expanded to key `goodbye` and the value of a function named goodbye with the specified parameters.

```
let say = {
  goodbye() {
    console.log("Bye")
  },
  hello() {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
}

say.hello()
```